# Codeigniter, pass parameter to a language file

Tags: codeigniter

Well, I know how to pass parameter to a view, it is documented, but how to pass parameter to a language file?
When all we can do is:

```
$this->lang->load('pages/downloads');
```

There I need a parameter passed with a querystring.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it by setting a session variable with a file name and later in the language file I remove it.

in the view:

```
if (isset($file)) {
      $this->session->set_userdata('file', $file );
    }
```

in the language file

```
if ($ci->session->has_userdata('file')) {
  $file = urldecode($ci->session->userdata('file'));
  $ci->session->unset_userdata('file');
}
```